# Fixar um elemento do tipo footer no rodapé da página

Tags: jquery, html, css, html5

Estou fazendo um trabalho para a faculdade onde fomos instruídos a aproveitar as novas tags semânticas do HTML5 (nav, section, footer, etc). Estou tendo problemas em fixar o footer ao fim da página. Já tentei usando CSS e jQuery, porém nada chegou próximo do resultado.

Esse é o código de uma das páginas:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Pizzaria Bolonha</title>
<link href="./css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="./js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="./js/jquery.cycle2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><img src="images/small_logo.png"/></li>
    <li><a href="./home.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="./pizzaria.html">A pizzaria</a></li>
    <li><a href="./horarios_precos.html">Horários e preços</a></li>
    <li><a href="./sabores.html">Sabores</a> </li>
    <li><a href="./bebidas.html">Bebidas</a></li>
    <li><a href="./contato.html" class="last">Contato</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<section>
  <div class="middle"> <br/>
    <center>
      <img src="./images/logo.png"/>
    </center>
    <br/>
    Em um ambiente confortável e aconchegante, a Pizzaria Bologna traz a você os melhores e mais variados sabores da mais deliciosa pizza italiana. Por aqui, priorizamos o atendimento de qualidade, o bem-estar e um sabor único. Nossas pizzas combinam sabores aprovados por pizzaiolos apaixonados com ingredientes selecionados cuidadosamente por uma nutricionista experiente, trazendo uma experiência gastronômica única.</div>
</section>
<footer>Pizzaria Bologna | Avenida Presidente Wenceslau Braz, 1172 - Guaira. Curitiba - PR | (41)3213-5200</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

E esse é o CSS que estou usando:

```
@charset "utf-8";
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,300);
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    background-color: #DDD;
}
h2 {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 20px;
}
section {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding-bottom: 60px;
}
.middle {
    width: 1200px;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: justify;
}
footer {
    clear: both;
    padding-top: 20px;
    background-color: #a20e06;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -40px;
}
nav {
    background-color: #06a20e;
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
}
nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
nav li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}
nav a {
    background: transparent;
    color: white;
    display: block;
    font: 20px/80px 'Open Sans';
    padding: 0 25px;
    border-right: solid 1px #07b30f;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
    -o-transition: all .25s ease;
    transition: all .25s ease;
}
nav a.last {
    border-right: none;
}
nav li:hover a {
    background: #07b30f;
}
iframe {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    border: 0;
    float: right;
}
#gallery {
    width: 990px;
    margin: auto;
}
#gallery img {
    border: 2px solid white;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #333;
    margin: 1px;
    -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
    -o-transition: all .25s ease;
    transition: all .25s ease;
}
#gallery img:hover {
    border: 2px solid #06a20e;
}
```

O que posso fazer para corrigir o erro e também melhorar a estruturação do site?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Essa é uma dúvida comum, e não conheço uma solução "canônica" para isso (a maioria das que vejo parece mais uma gambiarra). Um *workaround* é colocar todo o conteúdo da sua página [exceto o rodapé] em uma `div` separada e fazer com que seu tamanho mínimo seja `100%`:

HTML

```html
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <nav>
        ...
        </section>
    </div>
    <footer>
        ...
```

CSS

```css
#container { height: auto; min-height: 100%; }
```

[Fonte (SOen)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/689290/520779). [Exemplo no jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/vf83y/). Nota: ajustei o `margin-top` do `footer` para `-60px` para levar em conta o *padding* no topo. Não sei se fiz certo, mas o resultado parece ok (no fiddle está um pouco apertado, mas ao alargar a janela fica bom).

Aqui está [o mesmo exemplo com mais conteúdo na página](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/vf83y/1/). Nesse caso, o rodapé continua no final da página, visível somente ao se rolar até embaixo. E, desnecessário dizer, se o que você quer é que ele fique sempre visível e embaixo, basta usar `position: fixed` e deixar um espaço a mais no conteúdo principal para que se possa rolar até o final sem nada ficar obscurecido.

Comment: Muito obrigado, da maneira como você indicou ficou perfeito!